# Are file extensions required to correctly serve web content?

Tags: file-upload, browser, amazon-s3, file-extension

We're using Amazon S3 to store and serve images, videos, etc. When uploading this content we also always set the correct content-type (image/jpeg, etc.).

My question is this: Is a file extension required (or recommended) with this sort of setup? In other words, will I potentially run into any problems by naming an image "example" versus "example.jpg"?

I haven't seen any issues with doing this in my tests, but wanted to make sure there are any exceptions that I may be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions are just a means by which OS decides the operating program. As far as your scenario is concerned, as long as the content-type specifies the type, the extension doesn't matter. But why in the world, would you name a jpg file as .txt right ?

Regards